# Arcanist gives segmentation fault 11

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

I did an arc install-certificate but every arc call I do returns a "Segmentation fault: 11". I did get to enter the token. The trace of an arc diff doesn't help me very much:

```
$ arc diff --trace
libphutil loaded from '/xxx/arcinstall/libphutil/src'.
arcanist loaded from '/xxx/arcinstall/arcanist/src'.
Config: Reading user configuration file "/xxx/.arcrc"...
Config: Did not find system configuration at "/etc/arcconfig".
Working Copy: Reading .arcconfig from "/xxx/.arcconfig".
Working Copy: Path "/xxx" is part of `git` working copy "/xxx".
Working Copy: Project root is at "/xxx".
Config: Did not find local configuration at "/xxx/.git/arc/config".
>>> [0] <conduit> user.whoami() <bytes = 117>
>>> [1] <http> https://xxx.xx.xx/api/user.whoami
<<< [1] <http> 327,750 us
<<< [0] <conduit> 328,476 us
>>> [2] <exec> $ git diff --no-ext-diff --no-textconv --raw 'HEAD' --
>>> [3] <exec> $ git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
<<< [3] <exec> 21,249 us
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I'm not sure where to look to fix this :S. I'm working on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 5):

We've seen this specifically with Homebrew's PHP 5.5.30 on Mac OS X. Please update to PHP 5.6 while the upstream looks at possible causes.

Comment: I think you mention php v5.6 not homebrew

Comment: @chad-little thanks - upgrading to PHP 5.6 did fix it for me

Comment: Also noted on PHP 5.5.38_11 (OS X, installed via Homebrew)

Comment: I am forced to use PHP 5.5 locally (5.5.38).  Originally I had installed PHP from source and all was fine.  I switched PHP to Brew and, since, Archanist, as noted earlier, has been acting up with a segmentation fault.  My quick and dirty fix for now has been to switch to Brew's php56 version where Archanist works just fine and then revert back to php55 to be version compliant for the rest of my work.  Not pretty but...  The longer term solution would be to drop Brew's PHP in favour of the original but I don't have time to mess with this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You may try a couple of things (and I advise in this order):

- Ensure both libphutil and arcanist are up to date
- Ensure you PHP version is up to date
- Try disabling xdebug if enable in your php config

Comment: I've already checked number 2 and 3. Should I ensure libphutil is in a specific path or anything? Maybe it isn't referenced correctly? I don't know where I should put it... Currently it is residing in a folder at the same level as arcanist.

Comment: I see it loaded from the right path in the trace log so that can't be it.

Comment: To update those it's just `arc upgrade` or a `git pull` in both folders. Also you may wanna try updating your Phabricator server.

Comment: I've tried them both but to no avail. They are both newly installed btw.